# DbContext prevent duplicate insertion due to DbContext.Entity.Local

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class with an Initialize() method that basically tries to add "Tags" to my database, if a tag with a name doesn't exist.  The logic used here is simple:

```
// Class variables outside of the Initialize() method    
List<Tags> Tags = new List<Tags>();
List<string> TagNames = ...Some values;

public void Initialize()
{
    using (var context = Application.GetDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var tagName in TagNames)
        {
            var tag = context.Tags
            .Include(ti => ti.MonRequests
            .Select(r => r.Profiles))
            .FirstOrDefault<NWatchTag>(
                p => p.Name.Equals(
                    tagName,
                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
                    ));

            if (tag == null)
            {
                // Add tag to dbContext
                Trace.TraceInformation("Adding tag '{0}'.", tagName);
                tag = context.Tags.Add(
                    new NWatchTag(tagName)
                    {
                        IsSystem = true
                    }
                );
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        Tags = context.Tags.Where(x => TagNames.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
    }
}
```

This works fine, and it only adds the tag (distinguished by Name) once.

Now, there is a method that tries to use the `Tags` collection in order to tag some nodes.  The logic is as follows:

```
public void ApplyMonitoringTags(Node node)
{
    using (var context = Application.GetDbContext()) {

        node = context.Nodes.
            Include(x => x.Tags).
            FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == rootNode.Id);

        foreach (var tag in Tags)
        {
            if (!node.Tags.Contains(tag))
            {
                node.Tags.Add(tag);
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here, the context ends up adding the Tags to `context.Tags.Local` collection.
When `SaveChanges()` is called, it ends up doing an Insert for the tags again, and now I have tags with the same name created again.  The Node is then associated with the 'newly' created (duplicate) tags, instead of the tags that were created in the `Initialize()` method.

This class is re-used over a long period of time, so the `Initialize()` method should create the tags and maintain them in the `Tags` collection.  Any calls to `ApplyMonitoringTags()` should end up associating the Node with the already created tags.

How do I get around this?